# Equivalence between entanglement purification and quantum error correction

Tags: entanglement, error-correction, state-distillation, purification

I've recently been reading the seminal paper recently ([*BDSW 1996*](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9604024)), where they established the equivalence between 1-EPP (one-way classical communication) and error correction through explicit construction.

Is there are any similar results that hold for 2-EPP (two-way classical communication), or rigorous theoretical proof?

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/31567/55

Comment: @glS Thanks ... yes I was the OP for the other question since I've been thinking about related stuffs all these times ... I did not have a clear clue so I come for help :)